# Transform data streams (pagingData.map()) cannot in PagingData using java

Tags: android, android-paging-3

Transform data streams

[map red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBhlt.png)

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#guava-livedata

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation on this part is misleading.

The `PagingData.filter()` is declared in `PagingDataTransforms` as a Kotlin extension function, so in Java, it must be called like you'd call a static method.

So you need to use this instead `PagingDataTransforms.filter(pagingData)`.

Here's a complete example:

```java
PagingDataTransforms.filter(
    pagingData,
    ExecutorsKt.asExecutor(Dispatchers.getIO()),
    item -> {
        // Your filtering logic
        return true;
    }
);
```